# Parsing millisecond without padding in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, import

I'm unable to parse correctly the following datetime input from a file with pandas.read_tables:

```
2018/4/13 22:59:55.6 
2018/4/13 22:59:55.537  
2018/4/13 22:59:56.68
```

Which should be 6, 537 and 68 milliseconds respectively, and should be logged as 006, 537 and 068. However pandas returns 600, 537 and 680. For now I'm padding by hand before importing, but this is the third or fourth time I'm getting this issue so I can't believe I'm the only one !

Thanks all.

Comment: sounds like pandas is doing the right thing; having 0.6 actually mean 0.006 seems somewhat unusual behaviour and I'd expect to have to handle that specially

Comment: Are your input datetime elements actual strings?

Comment: is that a single column or two columns? and you can look at `zfill()`?

Comment: @9769953 yes this is exactly how it is in the source file

Comment: @MattR it is a single column, easily splittable though. I do use zfill for now in a very ugly way...

Comment: @SamMason I fully agree with you but I've seen it this way several times in industrial environments.

Comment: Split the strings beforehand (or possibly in your DataFrame using the `.str.` methods) on the decimal dot ".". Then, concatenate the two pieces using string formatting like so: `"{}{:>03}".format(part1, part2)`. That should pad the decimal part with zeros from the left, so that Pandas can parse the date-time string correctly.

Comment: @9769953 thanks for that I had the same kind of stuff but uglier.

Comment: @SamMason Does that mean you should interpret 22:4:55 as 22:40:55 ? not sure..

Comment: I wouldn't, and I think that would confuse a lot of people.  a dot in numeric fields commonly indicates the start of a decimal fraction, while colons are specially used times to indicate different fields.  your use is (ab)using a dot to indicate a millisecond field